# R rlang: use .x in map() with quosure?

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I am trying to pass a set of variables/values in a data.frame to a `map` function, but am not sure how to deal with the fact that `.x` refers to a quosure that needs to be evaluated: `mutate(df2 = map2(variable, value, ~filter(df1, .x==.y)))` A naive `!!.x` will not work.

Here my data.frame has one column for *variable*, one for *value*, that will be mapped in a filter call:

```r
tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) 
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   variable value
#>   <chr>    <chr>
#> 1 wool     A    
#> 2 tension  L
```

How can I pass these to filter? Should I declare instead *variable* as quosure? I tried a few approaches:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(warpbreaks)

tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered=map2(variable, value, ~filter(warpbreaks, .x==.y)))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   variable value data_filtered       
#>   <chr>    <chr> <list>              
#> 1 wool     A     <data.frame [0 × 3]>
#> 2 tension  L     <data.frame [0 × 3]>

tibble(variable=c(quo(wool), quo(tension)), 
       value= c("A", "L")) %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered=map2(variable, value, ~filter(warpbreaks, eval_tidy(.x)==.y)))
#> Error in eval_tidy(.x): object 'wool' not found
```

Comment: Are you looking for `~ filter(df1, !!sym(.x) == .y)`? This transforms your variable name to a symbol (i.e. something that looks like an R variable), and inserts it inside the `==` expression with `!!`.

Comment: What's the expected output you are trying to create? I'm struggling to understand what a filter nested in a map2 nested in a mutate is trying to achieve.

Comment: @LionelHenry Did  you get that part working? I tried with the two solutions (variable is string, variable is quosure) but don't get it working?

Comment: @Spacedman Expected output has data_filtered with the corresponding filtered rows (not 0 rows). Big picture is me trying something like `nest()` output, but with overlapping groups.

Answer (score 1):

Something weird goes on with the anonymous function evaluation of `.x`. To be honest I'm not sure what, but defining a function outside of the `map2` call seems to work alright (credit to @Lionel Henry for the `~ filter(df1, !!sym(.x) == .y)` bit:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) 

data(warpbreaks)

# doesn't work with anonymous function
tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered=map2(variable, value, ~ filter(warpbreaks, !!sym(.x) == .y)))
#> Error in is_symbol(x): object '.x' not found

# works when you define function outside of map2
temp <- function(x, y, data){
  filter(data, !!sym(x) == y)
}

tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered=map2(variable, value, temp, warpbreaks))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   variable value data_filtered        
#>   <chr>    <chr> <list>               
#> 1 wool     A     <data.frame [27 x 3]>
#> 2 tension  L     <data.frame [18 x 3]>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You can also do the following without the externally defined function:

```r
tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered = map2(variable, value, ~ filter(..3, ..3[[..1]] == ..2), warpbreaks))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   variable value data_filtered        
#>   <chr>    <chr> <list>               
#> 1 wool     A     <data.frame [27 x 3]>
#> 2 tension  L     <data.frame [18 x 3]>
```

Comment: Sometimes base R code can be neater and possibly easier to understand and without having to quote and de-quote expressions. This: `apply(df,1,function(r){warpbreaks[warpbreaks[[r[1]]] == r[2],,drop=FALSE]})` returns a list (instead of a tibble with a data frame list column) but its an equivalent structure. And very little "weird" things happen. And it doesn't break with new package releases.

Comment: I agree with you regarding code simplicity and base R, particularly for your example. In terms of OP's question, I generally operate on the assumption that OP's example is useful for their purpose outside of the scope of what's specifically in the question.

Comment: No problem with your answer, (I've not downvoted it!) but I think too many R users have never used square bracket subsetting, or `apply`, and I think it always a good idea to say "you could use base R for this just as (or more) easily".

Comment: @zack You had to create a named function because otherwise `!!` operates too early, when the first `mutate()` is called. Actually I should have suggested to use `.data[[name]]` instead of `!!sym(name)`. For that reason, and also because it is easier to understand than `!!`.

Comment: Thanks @LionelHenry, I've updated my answer to include what I think you are describing - if you'd like to answer yourself I'd happily remove it.

Comment: hmm no that's not what I meant ;) Can you remove the note please? I meant the `.data` pronoun created by tidy eval verbs like `filter()`. But actually there's a timing problem with the `.data` solution as well, so creating a named function is still the best way.

Comment: @Spacedman Using `apply()` with data frames seems a bad suggestion in general because of the conversion to matrix. The data frame must be mono-typed for this to work without surprises.

Comment: @LionelHenry yes but it seems a good idea to understand the surprises in base R and not have to worry about the surprises in every other add on package.

Comment: Are you campaigning against CRAN? Anyway, I have added an answer using your idea of mapping directly over the data frame.

Comment: thanks @zack the second solution is neat (and yes, your assumption that OP's question is just a simplification of a larger problem  was warranted), although I do not really understand the use of ..3. I thought I could use only ..1, ..2 with pmap. With map2, is ..3 referring to... the dataset? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou - `..3` refers to a third argument being passed to `map2` after the function call. It's utilizing the `...` argument `map2` allows. In this case, I'm passing `warpbreaks`. I wanted to make it an argument rather than calling it straight from the function for the solution to be more general. Hope that made sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're trying to use dplyr verbs in a nested way: there's a `filter()` inside `mutate()`. This works well for the normal use, but we need to be a little careful when using tidy eval features because they are applied very early, when the outer function is called. For this reason there's often a timing problem if you try to use `!!` or `.data` in the inner verb.

@zack's answer shows how you can decompose the problem in two steps to avoid the nested issue. In this case, another possibility is to omit the `mutate()` step by mapping directly over `df` (credit to @Spacedman for the idea). Here we're going to use `pmap()` which maps in parallel over a list or data frame:

```
# For pretty-printing
options(tibble.print_max = 5, tibble.print_min = 5)
warpbreaks <- as_tibble(warpbreaks)

pmap(df, ~ filter(warpbreaks, .data[[.x]] == .y))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 27 x 3
#>   breaks wool  tension
#>    <dbl> <fct> <fct>
#> 1     26 A     L
#> 2     30 A     L
#> 3     54 A     L
#> 4     25 A     L
#> 5     70 A     L
#> # … with 22 more rows
#>
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 18 x 3
#>   breaks wool  tension
#>    <dbl> <fct> <fct>
#> 1     26 A     L
#> 2     30 A     L
#> 3     54 A     L
#> 4     25 A     L
#> 5     70 A     L
#> # … with 13 more rows
```

Comment: thanks! But then I am still facing the problem on how to include this into my main data frame. Surprisingly, `df %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered= pmap(df, ~ filter(warpbreaks, .data[[.x]] == .y)))` does not seem to work!?

Comment: You can assign the list column in your data frame afterwards. Your snippet doesn't work because `.data[[` unquotes its argument (here, `.x`) too early. That's the same issue as using `!!` in a nested tidyeval function. I recognise this is not ideal, but if we fixed that we'd make other patterns harder to do. An easy fix is to give a name to your function and pass the function by name, as in Zack's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `R`'s native substitution tools, *rlang* is more valuable when dealing with environments but for more complex symbol substitution (nested for example) base R is easier (for me at least).

```
tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered=map2(variable, value, ~eval(bquote(
    filter(warpbreaks, .(sym(.x)) ==.y)))))

tibble(variable=c("wool", "tension"), 
       value= c("A", "L")) %>% 
  mutate(data_filtered=map2(variable, value, ~eval(substitute(
    filter(warpbreaks, X ==.y), list(X = sym(.x))))))

# output for either
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#       variable value data_filtered        
#          <chr>    <chr> <list>               
#   1 wool     A     <data.frame [27 x 3]>
#   2 tension  L     <data.frame [18 x 3]>
```

Comment: Nice! Interesting to see R native tool, though I guess `sym()` is still a rlang function?!

Comment: `sym` lives in *rlang* but it's reexported by *dplyr* (`dplyr::sym` exists), it is basically `base::as.name` or `base::as.symbol` (they're aliases) with different checks and treatment of corner cases so you could use those here as well. The idea here anyway was not to try to get free from *rlang* (*dplyr* imports it so it would not make much sense) but to offer a readable solution.